# Como fazer um loop condicional no WordPress dependendo da categoria?

Tags: php, wordpress

Preciso formular este código para responder aos requisitos de uma categoria especifica aonde dentro dela os posts serão apresentados de forma randômica. Para isso eu fiz este código  no `category.php` do template *Storyline*.

```
if(is_category(48)){        
    $args = array(
        'cat' => 48,
        'orderby' => 'rand'
    );
    $cp = new WP_Query($args);      
} else {        
    if(of_get_option('order-posts') == "ll" ){
    global $query_string;
        query_posts( $query_string . '&order=ASC' );
    }   
}
```

..., condição que já está funcionando mas preciso aplicar a seguinte condição em uma outra parte do código e não aparece erro, simplesmente não executa:

```
 if(is_category(48)){
      if(have_posts()) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
 } else {
      if($cp->have_posts()) : while ( $cp->have_posts() ) : $cp->the_post();
 }
```

Este código permite que na categoria **48** eu aplique um `'orderby'='rand'`. Resumindo, o que eu preciso é fazer com que este `if/else` funcione.

A diferença entre os `ifs` é que o segundo aplica condições de **new WP_Query** que o primeiro não aplica.

Comment: Em qual template está usando esse código? Aquele `global $ha` tem alguma coisa a ver com o problema? Qual erro que dá ao executar?

Comment: O `global $ha` não está relacionado com o problema apresentado. Estou usando no **category.php** do template **Storyline**. Não aparece erro,simplesmente não executa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como regra geral, mantenha-se afastado do `query_posts`, essa é a query principal e ao modificá-la é quase certo criar mais problemas que soluções, vide [*When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/12615). Para filtrá-la sem causar novas chamadas ao banco de dados usamos o `pre_get_posts` em `functions.php`, no seu caso:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'random_cat_sopt_33765' );

function random_cat_sopt_33765( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $get_cat = get_query_var( 'category_name' );
        if( $get_cat === 'uncategorized' ) {
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
        }
    }
}
```

Coloque o slug da sua categoria 48 no lugar de `uncategorized`.